# Unexpected value 'MatDialogRef' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to integrate Angular Material in Angular but getting following error. The program is compiled successfully but getting this issue in browser.

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MatDialogRef' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at eval (compiler.js:15226)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15201)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34385)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34346)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34240)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5551)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

I have imported MatDialogRef in app.module.ts

```
import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDialogRef,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

I have also imported it in the component where dialog html is saved.

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
```

export class ComposeMailComponent implements OnInit {

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ComposeMailComponent>,
      @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a working solution ?

Comment: Same problem like you: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyComponent -> MatDialogRef]:   Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 9):

You dont need to import **`MatDialogRef`**  inside app.module.ts, Change

From

**`import { MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';`**

To

**`import { MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';`**

and remove `MatDialogRef` from `imports` array

Comment: I have already tried it, but it did not work however I have changed it back to @angular/material. It still gives same error

Comment: @D555 did you remove matdialogref?

Comment: yes, did it just now.. but it gives new error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ComposeMailComponent -> MatDialogRef]

Comment: have you added ComposeMailComponent  under declarations

Comment: yes, I have added it in appmodule.ts as well as in SidebarComponent from where I trigger the dialogbar to open

Comment: can you double check if you have the correct code as mentioned above

Comment: checked again.. its similar to what you have mentioned above.

Comment: @yurzui do you find anything?

Comment: MatDialogRef should be injected in constructor of component that will be opened

Comment: If he uses component like `this.dialog.open(ComposeMailComponent` then it should work because this provider is created dynamically

Comment: i have done exactly the same thing.. have already injected MatDialogRef in constructor of component that will be opened

Comment: did you restart the application?

Comment: yes, i have tried almost everything but it give the same error. My application gets compiled properly but it gives error in browser

Answer (score 3):

add these in app.module.ts file

import { MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';

imports: [
   MatDialogModule
  ],

it will work fine